# How to make a table with flexible width columns in CSS

Tags: css

All:

Right now, I want to make a table which has spec like:

I. Table has table header and body. Table width is fixed to 800px; height is 500px; Each row is 20px high. 100% width; The header is fixed position, the body can scroll if overflow. The whole table is mapped to an array of objects, each object has a field called "name" and several attrs(all 4 digits number).

II. The first column from left is called "name", rest columns are sub attributes of the object with that name. The number of columns is dynamic depends on the object. All columns have text-flow:ellipsis to crop overlong text

III. The layout rule is(It actually requires very complex rule, but I think if anyone could just help me with the most basic, then I probably can figure out rest myself):

[1]. When show the attributes name. Make the attribute name not be cropped as possible as we can. But must guarantee the "name" column must no smaller than 300px(the name column can be cropped too); If the attribute name  has to be cropped, try to make all columns same width;

[2] If no attribute name and name cropped, and there is still space, assign the space to name column.

I am thinking using div and css to build this rather than table tr td(cos I think it could be harder to me to understand and control)

Thanks

Comment: We're not really here to build your solution for you. That said, if you want a nice, lightweight framework for a responsive grid/table. [Purecss](http://purecss.io/) is pretty good.

Comment: I'm not sure a table couldn't just do what you're describing all by itself. Give the leftmost column a min-width of 300px.